# WinPcap C++ program no longer compiles in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, compiler-errors, pcap, winpcap

Ok. So, we've had a project that's worked for a long time, and now today I opened it up, made a change to some file i/o, and tried to compile. I get ton's of errors, and I have no clue why. The project hasn't changed, directory structure hasn't changed. The only thing that has changed is a huge windows update the other day, but surely that wouldn't effect it (surely).

Here are the includes,

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

#include "pcap.h"
```

And here are the errors,

```
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(48): warning     C4995: 'gets': name was marked as #pragma deprecated
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(52): warning C4995: 'sprintf': name was marked as #pragma deprecated
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(55): warning C4995: 'vsprintf': name was marked as #pragma deprecated
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstring(21): warning C4995: 'strcat': name was marked as #pragma deprecated
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstring(22): warning C4995: 'strcpy': name was marked as #pragma deprecated
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cwchar(30): warning C4995: 'swprintf': name was marked as #pragma deprecated
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cwchar(31): warning C4995: 'vswprintf': name was marked as #pragma deprecated
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cwchar(33): warning C4995: 'wcscat': name was marked as #pragma deprecated
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cwchar(35): warning C4995: 'wcscpy': name was marked as #pragma deprecated
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\string(757): warning C4995: 'swprintf': name was marked as #pragma deprecated
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\string(766): warning C4995: 'swprintf': name was marked as #pragma deprecated
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\string(775): warning C4995: 'swprintf': name was marked as #pragma deprecated
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\ws2def.h(91): warning C4005: 'AF_IPX' : macro redefinition
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(460) : see previous definition of 'AF_IPX'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\ws2def.h(131): warning C4005: 'AF_MAX' : macro redefinition
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(479) : see previous definition of 'AF_MAX'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\ws2def.h(168): warning C4005: 'SO_DONTLINGER' : macro redefinition
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(402) : see previous definition of 'SO_DONTLINGER'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\ws2def.h(212): error C2011: 'sockaddr' : 'struct' type redefinition
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(485) : see declaration of 'sockaddr'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\ws2def.h(390): error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\ws2def.h(390): error C3805: 'constant': unexpected token, expected either '}' or a ','
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\ws2def.h(524): warning C4005: 'IN_CLASSA' : macro redefinition
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(287) : see previous definition of 'IN_CLASSA'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\ws2def.h(530): warning C4005: 'IN_CLASSB' : macro redefinition
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(293) : see previous definition of 'IN_CLASSB'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\ws2def.h(536): warning C4005: 'IN_CLASSC' : macro redefinition
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(299) : see previous definition of 'IN_CLASSC'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\ws2def.h(547): warning C4005: 'INADDR_ANY' : macro redefinition
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(304) : see previous definition of 'INADDR_ANY'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\ws2def.h(549): warning C4005: 'INADDR_BROADCAST' : macro redefinition
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(306) : see previous definition of 'INADDR_BROADCAST'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\ws2def.h(583): error C2011: 'sockaddr_in' : 'struct' type redefinition
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(312) : see declaration of 'sockaddr_in'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(132): error C2011: 'fd_set' : 'struct' type redefinition
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(68) : see declaration of 'fd_set'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(167): warning C4005: 'FD_SET' : macro redefinition
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(102) : see previous definition of 'FD_SET'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(176): error C2011: 'timeval' : 'struct' type redefinition
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(111) : see declaration of 'timeval'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(232): error C2011: 'hostent' : 'struct' type redefinition
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(167) : see declaration of 'hostent'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(245): error C2011: 'netent' : 'struct' type redefinition
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(180) : see declaration of 'netent'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(252): error C2011: 'servent' : 'struct' type redefinition
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(187) : see declaration of 'servent'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(264): error C2011: 'protoent' : 'struct' type redefinition
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(199) : see declaration of 'protoent'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(360): error C2011: 'WSAData' : 'struct' type redefinition
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(322) : see declaration of 'WSAData'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(458): error C2011: 'sockproto' : 'struct' type redefinition
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(494) : see declaration of 'sockproto'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(500): error C2011: 'linger' : 'struct' type redefinition
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(531) : see declaration of 'linger'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(513): warning C4005: 'SOMAXCONN' : macro redefinition
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(544) : see previous definition of 'SOMAXCONN'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(542): warning C4005: 'FD_READ' : macro redefinition
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(562) : see previous definition of 'FD_READ'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(545): warning C4005: 'FD_OOB' : macro redefinition
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(564) : see previous definition of 'FD_OOB'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(551): warning C4005: 'FD_ACCEPT' : macro redefinition
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(565) : see previous definition of 'FD_ACCEPT'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(554): warning C4005: 'FD_CONNECT' : macro redefinition
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(566) : see previous definition of 'FD_CONNECT'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(557): warning C4005: 'FD_CLOSE' : macro redefinition
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(567) : see previous definition of 'FD_CLOSE'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(1578): error C2375: 'accept' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(742) : see declaration of 'accept'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(1600): error C2375: 'bind' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(747) : see declaration of 'bind'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(1619): error C2375: 'closesocket' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(752) : see declaration of 'closesocket'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(1638): error C2375: 'connect' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(754) : see declaration of 'connect'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(1659): error C2375: 'ioctlsocket' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(759) : see declaration of 'ioctlsocket'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(1680): error C2375: 'getpeername' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(764) : see declaration of 'getpeername'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(1701): error C2375: 'getsockname' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(769) : see declaration of 'getsockname'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(1724): error C2375: 'getsockopt' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(774) : see declaration of 'getsockopt'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(1745): error C2375: 'htonl' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(781) : see declaration of 'htonl'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(1762): error C2375: 'htons' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(783) : see declaration of 'htons'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(1780): error C2375: 'inet_addr' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(785) : see declaration of 'inet_addr'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(1797): error C2375: 'inet_ntoa' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(787) : see declaration of 'inet_ntoa'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(1815): error C2375: 'listen' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(789) : see declaration of 'listen'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(1833): error C2375: 'ntohl' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(793) : see declaration of 'ntohl'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(1850): error C2375: 'ntohs' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(795) : see declaration of 'ntohs'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(1870): error C2375: 'recv' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(797) : see declaration of 'recv'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(1895): error C2375: 'recvfrom' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(803) : see declaration of 'recvfrom'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(1921): error C2375: 'select' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(811) : see declaration of 'select'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(1945): error C2375: 'send' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(818) : see declaration of 'send'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(1970): error C2375: 'sendto' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(824) : see declaration of 'sendto'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(1996): error C2375: 'setsockopt' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(832) : see declaration of 'setsockopt'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(2018): error C2375: 'shutdown' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(839) : see declaration of 'shutdown'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(2039): error C2375: 'socket' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(843) : see declaration of 'socket'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(2063): error C2375: 'gethostbyaddr' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(850) : see declaration of 'gethostbyaddr'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(2083): error C2375: 'gethostbyname' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(855) : see declaration of 'gethostbyname'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(2101): error C2375: 'gethostname' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(857) : see declaration of 'gethostname'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(2121): error C2375: 'getservbyport' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(861) : see declaration of 'getservbyport'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(2141): error C2375: 'getservbyname' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(865) : see declaration of 'getservbyname'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(2160): error C2375: 'getprotobynumber' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(869) : see declaration of 'getprotobynumber'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(2178): error C2375: 'getprotobyname' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(871) : see declaration of 'getprotobyname'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(2200): error C2375: 'WSAStartup' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(875) : see declaration of 'WSAStartup'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(2219): error C2375: 'WSACleanup' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(879) : see declaration of 'WSACleanup'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(2236): error C2375: 'WSASetLastError' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(881) : see declaration of 'WSASetLastError'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(2253): error C2375: 'WSAGetLastError' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(883) : see declaration of 'WSAGetLastError'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(2270): error C2375: 'WSAIsBlocking' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(885) : see declaration of 'WSAIsBlocking'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(2287): error C2375: 'WSAUnhookBlockingHook' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(887) : see declaration of 'WSAUnhookBlockingHook'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(2304): error C2375: 'WSASetBlockingHook' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(889) : see declaration of 'WSASetBlockingHook'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(2321): error C2375: 'WSACancelBlockingCall' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(891) : see declaration of 'WSACancelBlockingCall'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(2343): error C2375: 'WSAAsyncGetServByName' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(893) : see declaration of 'WSAAsyncGetServByName'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(2370): error C2375: 'WSAAsyncGetServByPort' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(901) : see declaration of 'WSAAsyncGetServByPort'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(2396): error C2375: 'WSAAsyncGetProtoByName' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(909) : see declaration of 'WSAAsyncGetProtoByName'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(2421): error C2375: 'WSAAsyncGetProtoByNumber' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(916) : see declaration of 'WSAAsyncGetProtoByNumber'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(2446): error C2375: 'WSAAsyncGetHostByName' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(923) : see declaration of 'WSAAsyncGetHostByName'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(2473): error C2375: 'WSAAsyncGetHostByAddr' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(930) : see declaration of 'WSAAsyncGetHostByAddr'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(2496): error C2375: 'WSACancelAsyncRequest' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(939) : see declaration of 'WSACancelAsyncRequest'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(2517): error C2375: 'WSAAsyncSelect' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(941) : see declaration of 'WSAAsyncSelect'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\ws2ipdef.h(75): error C2079: 'sockaddr_gen::Address' uses undefined struct 'sockaddr'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\ws2ipdef.h(76): error C2079: 'sockaddr_gen::AddressIn' uses undefined struct 'sockaddr_in'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\ws2ipdef.h(119): warning C4005: 'IP_TOS' : macro redefinition
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(352) : see previous definition of 'IP_TOS'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\ws2ipdef.h(120): warning C4005: 'IP_TTL' : macro redefinition
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(351) : see previous definition of 'IP_TTL'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\ws2ipdef.h(121): warning C4005: 'IP_MULTICAST_IF' : macro redefinition
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(346) : see previous definition of 'IP_MULTICAST_IF'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\ws2ipdef.h(122): warning C4005: 'IP_MULTICAST_TTL' : macro redefinition
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(347) : see previous definition of 'IP_MULTICAST_TTL'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\ws2ipdef.h(123): warning C4005: 'IP_MULTICAST_LOOP' : macro redefinition
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(348) : see previous definition of 'IP_MULTICAST_LOOP'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\ws2ipdef.h(124): warning C4005: 'IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP' : macro redefinition
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(349) : see previous definition of 'IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\ws2ipdef.h(125): warning C4005: 'IP_DROP_MEMBERSHIP' : macro redefinition
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(350) : see previous definition of 'IP_DROP_MEMBERSHIP'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\ws2ipdef.h(126): warning C4005: 'IP_DONTFRAGMENT' : macro redefinition
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(353) : see previous definition of 'IP_DONTFRAGMENT'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\ws2ipdef.h(193): error C2079: '_SOCKADDR_INET::Ipv4' uses undefined struct 'sockaddr_in'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\ws2ipdef.h(700): error C2011: 'ip_mreq' : 'struct' type redefinition
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(363) : see declaration of 'ip_mreq'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\ws2tcpip.h(664): error C3861: 'WSASetLastError': identifier not found
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\ws2tcpip.h(671): error C3861: 'WSASetLastError': identifier not found
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\ws2tcpip.h(709): error C3861: 'WSASetLastError': identifier not found
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\ws2tcpip.h(716): error C3861: 'WSASetLastError': identifier not found
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\ws2tcpip.h(760): error C3861: 'WSASetLastError': identifier not found
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\ws2tcpip.h(767): error C3861: 'WSASetLastError': identifier not found
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\ws2tcpip.h(807): error C3861: 'WSASetLastError': identifier not found
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\ws2tcpip.h(814): error C3861: 'WSASetLastError': identifier not found
1>c:\users\adam\documents\fagerman technologies\winpcap lib\wpdpack\include\pcap\pcap.h(168): error C2079: 'pcap_pkthdr::ts' uses undefined struct 'timeval'
1>c:\users\adam\documents\fagerman technologies\velodynepcap\velodynepcap\capture.cpp(217): warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
1>c:\users\adam\documents\fagerman technologies\velodynepcap\velodynepcap\capture.cpp(292): warning C4995: 'strcpy': name was marked as #pragma deprecated
1>c:\users\adam\documents\fagerman technologies\velodynepcap\velodynepcap\capture.cpp(301): warning C4995: 'strcpy': name was marked as #pragma deprecated
1>c:\users\adam\documents\fagerman technologies\velodynepcap\velodynepcap\capture.cpp(325): warning C4995: 'strcpy': name was marked as #pragma deprecated
1>c:\users\adam\documents\fagerman technologies\velodynepcap\velodynepcap\capture.cpp(336): warning C4995: 'strcpy': name was marked as #pragma deprecated
1>c:\users\adam\documents\fagerman technologies\velodynepcap\velodynepcap\capture.cpp(360): warning C4995: 'strcpy': name was marked as #pragma deprecated
1>c:\users\adam\documents\fagerman technologies\velodynepcap\velodynepcap\capture.cpp(371): warning C4995: 'strcpy': name was marked as #pragma deprecated
1>c:\users\adam\documents\fagerman technologies\velodynepcap\velodynepcap\capture.cpp(411): warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'unsigned long', possible loss of data
1>c:\users\adam\documents\fagerman technologies\velodynepcap\velodynepcap\capture.cpp(412): warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
1>c:\users\adam\documents\fagerman technologies\velodynepcap\velodynepcap\capture.cpp(558): warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'unsigned short', possible loss of data
1>c:\users\adam\documents\fagerman technologies\velodynepcap\velodynepcap\capture.cpp(563): warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'unsigned short', possible loss of data
1>c:\users\adam\documents\fagerman technologies\velodynepcap\velodynepcap\capture.cpp(568): warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'unsigned short', possible loss of data
1>c:\users\adam\documents\fagerman technologies\velodynepcap\velodynepcap\capture.cpp(587): warning C4995: 'strcpy': name was marked as #pragma deprecated
1>c:\users\adam\documents\fagerman technologies\velodynepcap\velodynepcap\capture.cpp(594): warning C4995: 'strcpy': name was marked as #pragma deprecated
1>c:\users\adam\documents\fagerman technologies\velodynepcap\velodynepcap\capture.cpp(611): warning C4995: 'strcpy': name was marked as #pragma deprecated
1>c:\users\adam\documents\fagerman technologies\velodynepcap\velodynepcap\capture.cpp(618): warning C4995: 'strcpy': name was marked as #pragma deprecated
1>c:\users\adam\documents\fagerman technologies\velodynepcap\velodynepcap\capture.cpp(667): warning C4800: 'void *' : forcing value to bool 'true' or 'false' (performance warning)
1>c:\users\adam\documents\fagerman technologies\velodynepcap\velodynepcap\capture.cpp(680): warning C4244: '=' : conversion from '__int64' to 'unsigned long', possible loss of data
1>
1>Build FAILED.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as this is an all of a sudden affair and I need to get it figured out today.

EDIT: So, apparently including WinSock2.h before Windows.h solves the errors. But now I still have a question. Why did this all of a sudden happen? I mean heck, I don't know if my program will work correctly now that I've had to throw a haphazard fix to get it to compile. What has happened?

Comment: `'gets': name was marked as #pragma deprecated` seriously, the project used `gets`???

Comment: You get tons of stuff from `winsock.h` redefined in `winsock2.h` and `ws2def.h`. Chase your `#include`s.

Comment: Mine doesn't, I'm guessing pcap might use it, but that's a widely used library. Read edit, I solved the compile errors but I'm confused as to why this happened all of a sudden.

Comment: Ah, wait: `c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(48):` seems to be just from including `cstdio`. What a relief.

Comment: Probably a conditional include in Windows.h that is not made when WinSock2.h has defined some symbol. (But that's just a guess.)

Comment: Yes, but.. Why have I never received any of these errors before? I've never included WinSock2.h until today to fix that error.

Comment: I guess it was the update the other day that changed a couple of header files.